# How to check if object instance property Promise[] contains a specific Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I develop the React app and use some globally available object instances in order to handle repetitive tasks in component's logic. The implementation is simple:

```js
class SomeService {
    // Some service logic
}

const someService = new SomeService();

export default someService;
```

Then I import the instances in React functional components using `import` and call the proper methods on these objects. This way I implemented the `APIService` responsible for fetching the data from remote:

```js
class APIService {
    async get<Entity extends IEntity>(
        url: string,
        data: IQueryParams<Entity>,
        onSuccess?: (response: IResponse) => void,
        onError?: (error: IResponseDetails) => void,
        onNotFound?: (error: IResponseDetails) => void
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        // Some logic
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

So whenever I want to do the GET request in my components I can use:

```js
APIService.get(url, data, (response: IResponse) => {
    // Success
), (error: IResponseDetails) => {
    // Error
});
```

Recently I decided to implement the `AbortController` functionality in the `APIService` class in order to abort the `fetch` requests when the components unmount. I'd like to implement it the following way:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const request = APIService.get(url, data, (response: IResponse) => {
        // Success
    ), (error: IResponseDetails) => {
        // Error
    });

    return () => {
        APIService.abort(request);
    }
}, []);
```

Under the hood the `APIService` class contains the `private queue: Promise<boolean>[]` property tracking all the pending promises attached to it during the `fetch` calls and removed when the promises are resolved.

The `APIService.abort` method is supposed to take the `Promise<boolean>` as the argument, find the promise in the `queue: Promise<boolean>[]` array and trigger the `AbortSignal`.

The problem I encounter is that I'm not able to check in the `APIService.abort` method if the passed promise is contained within the `queue` array (I add it in the `get` method using `this.queue.push(promise)`). I know that `Promise` is an object and is passed by reference but whether I try to find it in the `queue` array using `this.queue.indexOf(promise)` (which always returns `-1`) or by the `===` comparison, it doesn't detect the promise that has been added (like the reference was changed at some point).

Interestingly, the lookup in the `abort` method works correctly if I make the `queue` property public and call it outside the class:

```js
APIService.queue.push(request);
APIService.abort(request);
```

But if the `push` is done inside the `APIService.get` method, it doesn't work. What am I missing? Is there any way I can understand this behavior?

I tried to extend the `queue` type to the following:

```js
private queue = {
    id: number,
    promise: Promise<boolean>
}[]
```

And pass the `Math.random()` as the `id` when adding the new promise to the `queue` (in order to see if the object is not instantiated somewhere else) but doing the lookup in the `abort` method showed that the values are consistent (although the passed argument still doesn't occur in `this.queue[i].promise` for `i < this.queue.length`).

I also experimented with `setTimeout` in order to see if the `Promise` reference doesn't change somehow during the state change but I didn't observe any behavior like this.

Live example: [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mpmr1c?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Why are you creating an asynchronous API now in 2024 that even supports plain callbacks at all instead of just relying on the returned promise?  That's just a mess, more work to test and a more confusing API to present to the developer.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for your feedback. I wanted to have the separate argument for the case in which the resource is not found. I think it's more readable to have it as an optional argument rather than putting the conditions everytime in the `.catch` chain method.

Comment: And that nuance says that you should support plain callbacks instead of have the API just use promises?  Wouldn't be my choice for an API I was designing.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you have any sources/materials that can help me understand why promises are that much better over async functions with callbacks?

Comment: You can do your own Google search for "advantages of programming with promises".  The list is long.  Promises, along with `await` have become a standard, built-in part of the language for a very good reason - they make asynchronous code, asynchronous error handling and asynchronous error propagation a whole lot easier and the advantages multiply when you have multiple asynchronous operations either in sequence, in a loop or running in parallel.

Comment: Plus, why would you use an `async` function AND callbacks.  This means you're returning a promise AND using callbacks.  How is the developer using this API supposed to know which is used for what?  Are the results or errors in the promise?  Does the returned promise even do anything?  Or, do you have to supply callbacks to get completion, error and notfound info?  At least, pick one or the other - preferably just the promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for your time, after reading more about it I decided to implement these methods as `get(url: string, data: IQueryParams, onNotFound?: () => void): Promise<IResponse> { ... }` promises.

Comment: Moving in the right direction, but if it's not found, what happens to the returned promise?  Still a bit confusing.  How is one supposed to code the promise `.then()` and `.catch()` if there's still this other notfound callback?

Comment: I thought about rejecting the promise but it'll also run the `.catch()` handler. So in this case adding the condition everytime to the `.catch()` seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the push is done inside the `APIService.get` method, it doesn't work. What am I missing?

The reason is that your `get` method is declared as `async`, which means it creates ad returns its own `Promise` that is wrapping the execution of the function body. So when you create a promise inside the function, push it to your queue, and then `return` it, all that'll do is to resolve the outer (implicit) promise with the explicitly returned one. While they will settle with the same result, they are distinct objects. So you could remove the `async` to make this work.

> I'd like to implement it the following way, where the `APIService.abort` method is supposed to take the `Promise<boolean>` as the argument, find the promise in the `queue` array and trigger the `AbortSignal`.

That is not how abort signals are designed to be used anyway. Instead, accept the abort signal as an argument to your `get` method! Create an abort controller in your effect, and pass its signal, then trigger it from the effect cleanup function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const request = APIService.get(url, data, (response: IResponse) => {
        // Success
    ), (error: IResponseDetails) => {
        // Error
    }, controller.signal);

    return () => {
        controller.abort();
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right. As it comes to the `AbortController` it's already implemented within the `APIService` in the actual code. Thanks to that I don't have to create `AbortController`s in `useEffect` hooks everytime I want to retrieve something from the API (not very DRY). I didn't elaborate on that because I believed it was not related to the problem.

Comment: If you want to dry this up, write a wrapper for the effect callback that passes just the signal, ie. `useEffect(abortable(signal => APIService.get(url, data, …, signal)), [])`. Or make `APIService.get` return the cleanup function - it's not clear why you are returning a `Promise<boolean>` that you are not using anywhere. In any case, don't use a promise as the key to identify a request.